# Display specific code based on post category

Tags: wordpress, post

I have different movie categories but I want the drama posts to have a different layout from the other genre.

```
<?php
if (in_category("drama")){
   //activate a specific code

}

elseif (in_category("other genre")){
   //activate a different code
```

Comment: I found this link after posting my answer. Thought it might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386487/wordpress-functions-php-use-different-page-template-for-each-post-category

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful plugins available to achieve your requirements,

Here couple of useful plugins,
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-template/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-templates/